# Need Netty server properties for Spring Boot and Spring Webflux

Tags: reactor-netty

We have migrated Zuul gateway application to spring cloud gateway. Spring cloud gateway is running on reactive Netty server. We want to replace below tomcat properties with Netty server properties. Could please provide Netty properties.

**Technology: java 17, Spring Boot and spring Webflux
**

```
server.tomcat.accept-count = 100
server.tomcat.max-connections = 10000
server.tomcat.max-threads = 200
server.tomcat.max-swallow-size = 20MB
server.tomcat.max-http-form-post-size = 20MB
```

Answer (score 0):

Those all properties are not required netty server.please set idle-timeout for closing TCP connections .it is enough